# Expected behavior of DeserializeWithLengthPrefix on incomplete message stream

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm not really sure if this is a bug or something I'm not seeing, so thought I'd post it as a question first.

If I call DeserializeWithLengthPrefix on a stream of say 1024 length, and the entire message takes up 5000, I get an 'Attempted to read past end of stream' exception.  I thought it just returns null, and I have other code that appears to behave that way.

The context is in a dotnetty decoder I'm trying to get working.  The stream I'm passing to DeserializeWithLengthPrefx is one I obtain from ReadOnlyByteBufferStream.

Comment: A bit more info.  If I call TryReadLengthPrefix that returns the correct full length.  Assuming it shares the same logic with DeserializeWithLengthPrefix.

Comment: Essentially, query the length with `TryReadLengthPrefix` and either buffer that much data or fail eagerly